# Does this trigger update Case object and Contact object fields?

Tags: trigger, case, contact, fields, update

I just want to see if I am going about this the right way. Here is my code:

```
trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (after insert)
{

    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Case c : Trigger.new)
    {
         contactIds.add(c.ContactId);
    }

    //Update Contacts
    Map<ID, Contact> mapContacts = new Map<ID, Contact>([SELECT Id FROM Contact where Id IN :contactIds]);
    System.debug(mapContacts);
    List<Contact> contactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    For(Case caseOb : Trigger.new)
    {
        Contact cont = mapContacts.get(caseOb.ContactId);
        cont.Country__c = caseOb.CountryWebFormText__c;
        contactToUpdate.add(cont);
    }

    update contactToUpdate;

    Map<Id, Contact> mapUpdatedContacts = new Map<Id,Contact>();
    For(Contact cons : contactToUpdate)
    {
        mapUpdatedContacts.put(cons.Id,cons);
    }

    //Update Cases
    List<Case>  caseList = [SELECT Id, CountryWebFormText__c, Newsletter__c, Country_of_Origin__c  FROM Case];
    List<Area__c> areaList = [SELECT Name, Id From Area__c];
    for(Case caseObj : caseList)
    {
        for(Area__c a : areaList)
        {
            if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Name.equals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c))
            {
                caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c.equals(a.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    update caseList;

}
```

What it is supposed to do is update the Case country field and the Contact(that is related to that particular Case) country field if text entered in a country field matches any of Area__c's list of countries.

Comment: While you update caseList, You need to perform an action in if statement. I am talking about this code: if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Name.equals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c))
            {
                caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c.equals(a.Name);
            }

Comment: What are you trying to do with equal statement inside if blocks?

Comment: @JavaAster I should probably change that to '=' right?

Comment: n.b. since you are using for loops, the loop variable `c`, `caseOb`, `caseObj` do not need to be different and as such create readability issues; furthermore `cons` is not particularly evocative of a Contact (singular). Stick to consistent variable names for your sobjects - for example `cs` for Case and `con` for Contact (or anything else you are comfortable with).

Comment: @Nik Yes to '=' and you should always bulify your code using list rather than iterating your code over loops. Take a note of crop1645's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do following way while updating case:

```
    List<Case>  caseList = [SELECT Id, CountryWebFormText__c, Newsletter__c, Country_of_Origin__c  FROM Case];
    List<Area__c> areaList = [SELECT Name, Id From Area__c];
    List<Case>  bulkifyList = new List<Case>();
        for(Case caseObj : caseList)
        {
            for(Area__c a : areaList)
            {
                if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Name.equals(caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c))
                {
                    caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c = a.Name;
                    bulkifyList.add(caseObj);
                }
            }            
        }

        update bulkifyList;
```

Comment: Thank you @JavaAster I will keep that in mind from now on.